# No Jobs Ran in the Last 12 Hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I noticed that none of my jobs on my server ran in the last 12 hours.  SQL Server Agent is online, but I have had to "reset" all of my job scheduels (go in change it to something new and then change the schedule back to it's original settings) for the jobs to start running again.  Has anyone ever had this problem before and know what causes it?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com would be a better fit for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server was down during the interval.  Jobs are now running on schedule